# Should the "Save Profile" button be always enabled?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

When I edit my profile and make some changes, I get the "Your profile has been saved successfully" message. However, the "Save Profile" button is kept enabled and clicking on it reloads the message even if no changes were made:

[image: Save Profile]

I don't know if it's by design, but I think it's a bit confusing; you can't really know if you made changes that you want to keep or it's enabled since it always is. I think that disabling it if there are no changes is neater and more straightforward.

What's the motivation behind keeping it enabled? I know it's harmless and not a big deal, but don't you agree that it's much better to disable it if no changes were made? I see that in almost every site I know, having it will improve the user experience, at least for me.

Can we enable it only when changes are made? Or at least don't send the save post if you don't do any changes. It simply doesn't feel correct for me.

Comment: This seems like it's only a problem if you became distracted while editing your profile (or perhaps some anxiety over not being completely 100% sure it has saved) but as long as you don't see any changes you *don't* want to keep in your profile, there's no harm in saving again before leaving the page.

Comment: @BSMP It's a common practice used by almost every site I know. Don't you agree with me that it's better to disable it if there're no changes?

Comment: I disagree that disabling it makes any difference. So I saved a profile that was already saved, so what? Let's keep the developers working on important bug fixes and not change tracking for the sake of a button.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I don't schedule their work. I only suggest improvements whenever I feel there should be.